# How to call Map functions on object that returns Map with type Any in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a function that returns an `Any` value where the actual value is a `Map` like

```
Any = Map(EFO -> [{"invalidPositions":false,"ft":false,"synState":[1]}]
```

This makes the compiler complain when I try to call methods of the Map class on the resultant object. How can I cast this object in such a way that I can call methods of the Map class?

Comment: `.asInstanceOf[Map[Any, Any]]` - however, the moment you have an **Any** in your code you have a  design error, and the moment you add a cast in your code you have just shutdown the typechecker of the compiler _(which is the most important aspect of the compiler)_.Also, remember the cast may fail in runtime in case your assumptions are not correct. - Meaning, you are basically just programming in **Python** with fancy syntax rather than **Scala**.

Comment: BTW, if you want and can, it may be better to explain why you end up with a value of type **Any** so we can provide you with alternatives to avoid that.

Comment: I am working with the `ujson` library and it returns object of type `Any` as part of call to `ujson.value`.

Comment: I am not familiar with **uJson** but I am pretty sure Li provided a typesafe way of reading JSON values. Maybe try opening a new question showing the json you are trying to read and how you are trying to read it and probably someone familiar with that library will pop up to help. You may also try asking in its gitter channel-

Comment: Thank you, Luis. I have posted another question here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67408338/mapping-function-over-ujson-values>.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned abvoe that you ended up with an `Any` value by using ujson library, so, this problem is more specific to that particular library. You can solve your problem using this approach:

```scala
import upickle

val s = """
{
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/lihaoyi/Ammonite/releases/17991367",
    "assets_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/lihaoyi/Ammonite/releases/17991367/assets",
    "upload_url": "https://uploads.github.com/repos/lihaoyi/Ammonite/releases/17991367/assets{?name,label}"
}"""

upickle.default.read[Map[String, String]](s)
```

Note: If you want to resolve the parsed json value to a particular scala case class you have to define an impilict for read/write like:

```scala
case class Rec(url: String, assets_url: String, upload_url: String)

implicit val recRW = upickle.default.macroRW[Rec]

upickle.default.read[Rec](s)
```

Here is the ammonite repl output:

```scala
@ s
res10: String = """
{
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/lihaoyi/Ammonite/releases/17991367",
    "assets_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/lihaoyi/Ammonite/releases/17991367/assets",
    "upload_url": "https://uploads.github.com/repos/lihaoyi/Ammonite/releases/17991367/assets{?name,label}"
}"""

@ upickle.default.read[Map[String, String]](s)
res11: Map[String, String] = Map(
  "url" -> "https://api.github.com/repos/lihaoyi/Ammonite/releases/17991367",
  "assets_url" -> "https://api.github.com/repos/lihaoyi/Ammonite/releases/17991367/assets",
  "upload_url" -> "https://uploads.github.com/repos/lihaoyi/Ammonite/releases/17991367/assets{?name,label}"
)

@ upickle.default.read[Rec](s)
res12: Rec = Rec(
  "https://api.github.com/repos/lihaoyi/Ammonite/releases/17991367",
  "https://api.github.com/repos/lihaoyi/Ammonite/releases/17991367/assets",
  "https://uploads.github.com/repos/lihaoyi/Ammonite/releases/17991367/assets{?name,label}"
)
```

Reference: https://www.lihaoyi.com/post/HowtoworkwithJSONinScala.html